# Ugrade to 20.04 point release - how to increase boot partition

Tags: boot-partition

When I try to upgrade to Utuntu 20.04.1 I get the message that my boot partition is too small. How can I increase my boot partition (I already removed all the old kernels).

[image]

Comment: The issue is not your /boot partition, but the there is insufficient space in / as you've filled it with applications, or user files (if you don't have a separate /home partition).  I too find 29gb too tight, esp. come *release-upgrade* time..  Re-read the message in your paste.  You need space to download the new packages (in *deb* format), then un-compress & install each package, before the clean occurs at the end.. ie. need many GB free)

Comment: did you do what is asked on line 3 and 4?

Comment: Yes, I already emptied the trash and clean up. After removing some old snaps it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not your `/boot` partition, but the insufficient space in `/` as you've filled it with applications, or user files (if you don't have a separate `/home` partition).

I too find 29 GB too tight, especially when it's time for a release upgrade.

Re-read the message in your paste. You need space to download the new packages (in deb format), then uncompress and install each package, before the clean occurs at the end, i.e., need many GBs free, you've almost enough but are 212MB short. And I'd suggest creating more space than that (*better safe than sorry in my experience*).